# How to change background of a input textbox after focus?

Tags: html, css

Here, I am trying to change the background color of the input after I write something in the textbox. Whenever I focus, then it will change the background color to white and it will remain white for the rest of time.

```
<input type="text" class="
```

```css
.contact-form input,
.contact-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background-color: #353b48;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}

.contact-form input:focus {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background-color: #353b48;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #207398;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="nameZone" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" style="color: black;">
        <input type="email" class="emailZone" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" style="color: black;">
        <input type="text" class="subjectZone" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" style="color: black;">
        <textarea class="messageZone" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="color: black;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remark: The top part of code is broken?

However, I've assumed you want to kept the gray-ish background while typing in data. I think you could use `!important`. The `:focus` part shall be redundant.

```css
.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea {
    background-color: #353b48 !important;
}
```

Snippet is the part of updated code. Btw, your inline css `color:black` has overrule the internal css `color:white`.

```css
.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px 0;
background-color: #353b48 !important;
border: none;
outline: none;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form">
  <input type="text" class="nameZone contact-form" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" style="color: black;">
  <textarea class="messageZone" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="color: black;"></textarea>
</div>
```